# Pass a React component as a param to another React component

Tags: reactjs, parameter-passing, jsx

I'm looking for a way to pass a react as param to other react and access it: I've tried something like:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <someReactFunction 
    param1={['test','test1']} 
    param2={[{<someOtherReactFunction someParam={testParam || ''} />}]} 
  />, 
  document.getElementById('someDiv'));
```

But I get JSX value should be either an expression or a quoted JSX text pointing to `document.getElementById('someDiv')`

**EDIT** After correcting some syntax error I get:

`: Unexpected token` Error pointing to the symbol `<` at `[{<someOtherReactFunction`

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's your use case?

Comment: my use case is to dynamically generate tab content..the tab layout (ie, menu, and their corresponding div's) is created by  `someReactFunction ` and The `tab div` content is generated by `someOtherReactFunction`

Comment: The best thing for you then would be to restructure your components. Have `someReactFunction` render `someOtherReactFunction`. Pass `someParam` first to `someReactFunction` and then down to `someOtherReactFunction`

Comment: the problem is `someOtherReactFunction` is dynamic.. for ex a tab can have any content like form, table, div, img etc,... with the feature I'm trying to achieve I can replace `someOtherReactFunction` param with `someAwsomeFunction` that would fill in the div accordingly without messing up the layout! If I restructure the code the way you suggest then I have to restrict `someOtherReactFunction` to any one of the UI component which I don't want to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may not be the best practice but got around what I was trying to do:

Pass the inner react component as a `value` to an object with some namespaced `property` something like:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <someReactFunction 
    param1={['test','test1']} 
    // `_treatAsComponent` is my specific name spaced key
    param2={[{'_treatAsComponent' : <someOtherReactFunction someParam={testParam || ''} />}]} 
  />, 
  document.getElementById('someDiv'));
```

And in your `someReactFunction` function loop over the array and do something like:

```
var SomeReactComponent = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    param1: React.PropTypes.array,
    param2: React.PropTypes.arrayOf(React.PropTypes.object).isRequired
  },
  render: function() {
     // since I have only one element I access it directly else you can loop over it if you have multiple arguments
    //now check the key to determine action to take
    if(param2[0]._treatAsComponent) {
        return (<div>{item[key]}</div>);
   }
    else if(param2[0]._treatAsHTML) {
        return (<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: param2[0]._treatAsHTML}}></div>);
  }
  else{
       return(//some default handling or errors);
 }
});
```

This way I've added more dynamic functionality for a given UI component. Is it the best practice?? Probaly not... but, is helping me what I'm trying to achieve..if any one has better solution please point me to that.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you should structure your code:

```
var SomeOtherReactComponent = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    someParam: React.PropTypes.string.isRequired
  },
  render: function() {
    var tabContent;
    if(this.props.someParam === '') {
      tabContent = "Oh no, this tab is empty!"
    } else {
      tabContent = this.props.someParam;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {tabContent}
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var SomeReactComponent = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    param1: React.PropTypes.array,
    param2: React.PropTypes.string
  },
  getDefaultProps: function() {
    return {
      param1: ['test', 'test1'],
      param2: ''
    };
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        {'This is someReactComponent. Below me is someOtherReactComponent.'}
        <SomeOtherReactComponent someParam={this.props.param2} />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<SomeReactComponent param2={'Awesome Tab Content'} />, document.getElementById('someDiv'));
```

Your components can be very dynamic. Render can have logic in it, it doesn't need to be a static view. All it needs to be us "pure", which in React world means deterministic: give a component the same props/state and every time it should give you the same render output.

Comment: what if I decide to call `SomeAwsomeReactComponent `  which is defined as `var SomeAwsomeReactComponent  = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
     <a {...this.props.someParam} href="javascript:;" role="button" className={(this.props.className || '') + ' btn'} />
    );
  }
}),`  I should go into the function and replace `SomeReactComponent ` with `SomeAwsomeReactComponent ` or duplicate the entire function and just change `SomeReactComponent ` to `SomeAwsomeReactComponent ` and use some hack on parameter passed to decide which inner function to call..

Comment: +1 for `deterministic: give a component the same props/state and every time it should give you the same render output`

Comment: Your components should be laid out as a hierarchy, with the `render` function of a parent component deciding what the child component(s) should be based on the props/state. Child components should have zero knowledge of their parents. So, you should write the `render` function of the parent, in this case, `SomeReactComponent`, with all the logic it needs to decide which components, if any, should be rendered below it. Not sure what else I can tell you - I think you're thinking about components like global functions, where they all know about each other. That's not how React is meant to work.

Comment: thanks for trying your best to explain..one last resort...can I pass `SomeOtherReactComponent` as a string param to `SomeReactComponent` and evaluate that as react compnent ie, `<SomeOtherReactComponent />` inside SomeReactComponent (like a hack) ?

Comment: Yes, but it would be really bad practice. Take a look at the doc son [Multiple Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html). Maybe that will help?